# What's the rationale for std::vector's swap invalidating the end() iterator?

Tags: c++, c++20, std

The obvious (to me) way to implement `vector::end()` would be to return an iterator with a pointer just past the last element, which would remain the same after a `swap()`.

However, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) claims that `swap` invalidates the `end()` iterator, although I don't see where that happens in [the spec](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/vector#lib:swap,vector), at least for C++20.  Is cppreference correct?  If so, what is the rationale for doing so--does invalidating `end()` allow some sort of non-obvious optimization?

Comment: Re: where it is in the spec. [**\[container.requirements.general\]/9**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/container.requirements#general-9):  Every iterator referring to an element in one container before the swap shall refer to the same element in the other container after the swap. It is unspecified whether an iterator with value `a.end()` before the swap will have value `b.end()` after the swap.

Comment: Yeah, I could see why for a linked list or a tree or something end() might point to a sentinel node inside the container.  So are you saying this is just accidental that they didn't specify anything different for a vector?

Comment: The actual iterator returned by `end()` is implementation-defined, and need not have an obvious relationship to the other iterators in the container.

Comment: A feasible (and common!) way of implementing `std::vector` is using a pair of pointers (one pointing to the first element of a dynamically allocated array, another pointing one-past-the-end of that array).   `std::vector::swap()` will then just swap that pair of pointers.   Problem is, that allows `std::vector::end()` to simple return a reference by dereferencing that "one-past-the-end" pointer.   The two end pointers will be non-equal, so their end iterators would not be equal - and swapping the two vectors will have a net effect of swapping their end iterators.

Comment: @MarkRansom I understand that `end()` could be implemented some other way, but the standard library seems to be designed in such a way that you can't really take advantage of this.  E.g., if `end()` were a null pointer or something, then a normal iterator would have to keep track of what vector it points to, which would make iterators less efficient.  Or maybe there's something I'm just not seeing, so how would an implementation take advantage of being able to invalidate end() on a swap?

Comment: @Peter why wouldn't the past the end pointer be equal after a swap?  If you do `a.swap(b)`, my contention is that with the most straightforward implementation, `a.end()` before the swap will the the same as `b.end()` after the swap.  Why would they not be equal?  Unless I'm misunderstanding something even bigger, but I assume all iterators point into the new container after a swap.

Comment: @MarkRansom Come on, there's no way `end()` is implemented in any way other than giving you the (wrapped) pointer past the end. It's not in the standard but it might as well be.

Comment: Uniformity of interface is good. Adding a special case for vectors is not necessarily a good thing at all.

Comment: @user3188445   My point is that there are implementation approaches in which the end pointers would not be equal.   The standard is about what is to be achieved, leaving freedom for implementation choices.  And it doesn't dictate (what some might consider to be) the "most straight-forward" implementation - that is up to developers of implementations.

Comment: @Peter Yes, and my question is name one implementation approach in which the end pointers are not equal.  Every single one I can think of is categorically worse than the obvious implementation, so either this isn't about performance (maybe they want some debugging version of the standard library to flag errors for certain undefined behavior like dereferencing end iterators), or maybe I'm missing some implementation technique, or maybe this is just an oversight on the part of the committee.  The latter could be, because the language invalidating end() is not vector-specific.

Comment: @user3188445 The standard leaves it undefined *because it does not seem important* to define it one way or the other.  Surely you would agree that it is poor software design for a piece of code to make use of `a.end()` to be equal to `b.end()` after `a.swap(b)`, regardless of whether that could be defined to be correct.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth No I wouldn't agree that's bad software design.  Certainly no worse that assuming `a.begin()` is equal to `b.begin()` after a swap, which is ensured by the standard.  Moreover, I would argue it is very important to avoid unnecessary undefined behavior in the standard, since this just makes C++ code less reliable than other code.  (In some cases undefined behavior is important for performance, which is fine.)

Comment: It is poor software design if it makes code difficult to read. I would definitely think that a variable `auto it = a.begin();` would, to a reader, always seem to point to an element of `a`. If you swap `a` and `b`, I don't care very much whether or not the standard guarantees that `it` now points into `b` -- it is at the very least confusing to any reader trying to figure out what `it` now points to. (Recall that there may be pages of code between the initialization of `it` and its use.)

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth if you have pages of code between the initialization of a variable and it's use, then I would argue that's poor design.  If you have iterators that are not tightly coupled to their ends, that's also poor design, which is why C++20 introduced better, less error-prone algorithms in the `std::ranges` namespace that take ranges instead of individual start and end iterators.  But now if you turn a vector into a range and then subsequently swap the vector, the range is no longer valid.  For no discernable benefit.  So I think the `end()` invalidation is an oversight.